# Is there free or open source software for checking PDF/A compliance?

Tags: pdf

> PDF/A is an ISO-standardized version of the Portable Document Format
> (PDF) specialized for the digital preservation of electronic
> documents.

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF/A)

This is great, but are there any free tools for checking the compliance of a single PDF file with any of the PDF/A sub-standards (PDF/A-1, PDF/A-2, PDF/A-3)?

On [this](http://www.pdfa.org/2011/08/validating-pdfa/) (old) website I have found a list of commercially available tools:

- **Acrobat 8 Preflight** (developed by callas software)
- PDF Tools AG: **3-Heights PDF Validator**
- LuraTech: **LuraDocument PDF Validator**
- Seal Systems: **PDF Checker**
- Intarsys: **PDF/A Live!**
- callas: **pdfaPilot**
- Apago: **PDF Appraiser** (sold by Actino)

However, given the importance of this subject, I hope that there is some sort of freely available tool. As a vision, it would be nice if an established open-source PDF toolkit such as [poppler](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/) supported such an analysis.

Comment: Do you want to check whether the document claims to be PDF/A compliant, or do you want to really check whether it is PDF/A compliant? In the first case, you would need a tool to display the metadata, such as Adobe Reader. In the second case, you most likely won't get around a commercial tool (because determining the compliance is not a trivial task).

Comment: I want to check for compliance. I am aware that this is not a trivial task. Still, there are many highly complex and high-quality PDF codes out there that are open source (ghostscript and poppler, just to name two), so I think it is not a fair assumption to infer the availability of free or OS software from the *complexity* of the task :-). But I guess you also have some experience in the field and did an internet search? :)

Comment: There is no such thing as a free PDF/A validator. The European Commission has started a project to create such a validator. You can read more about it here: http://www.pdfa.org/news/a-consortium-including-the-pdf-association-wins-phase-1-of-an-eu-commission-tender-to-create-a-definitive-pdfa-validator/ As it is not a trivial task, you can imagine that this project is far from completed. I am not aware of any deliverables that are already available.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [veraPDF](http://verapdf.org/software/):

- open source (veraPDF is dual-licensed under the GNU General Public License v3 or later (GPLv3+) and Mozilla Public License v2 or later (MPLv2+).)
- Linux, Mac OS X, Microsoft Windows
- written in Java
- CLI or GUI

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image][image]

```
Usage: veraPDF [options] FILES
  Options:
    -x, --extract
       Extracts and reports PDF features.
       Default: false
    --fixmetadata
       Performs metadata fixes.
       Default: false
    -f, --flavour
       Chooses built-in Validation Profile flavour, e.g. '1b'. Alternatively,
       supply '0' or no argument for automatic flavour detection based on a file
's
       metadata.
       Default: 0
       Possible Values: [0, 1a, 1b, 2a, 2b, 2u, 3a, 3b, 3u]
    --format
       Chooses output format.
       Default: mrr
       Possible Values: [xml, mrr, text]
    -h, --help
       Shows this message and exits.
       Default: false
    -l, --list
       Lists built-in Validation Profiles.
       Default: false
    --maxfailures
       Sets maximum amount of failed checks.
       Default: -1
    --maxfailuresdisplayed
       Sets maximum amount of failed checks displayed for each rule.
       Default: 100
    -o, --off
       Turns off PDF/A validation
       Default: false
    --policyfile
       Select a policy schematron or XSL file.
    --prefix
       Sets file name prefix for any fixed files.
       Default: veraFixMd_
    -p, --profile
       Loads a Validation Profile from given path and exits if loading fails.
       This overrides any choice or default implied by the -f / --flavour option
.
    -r, --recurse
       Recurses through directories. Only files with .pdf extensions are
       processed.
       Default: false
    --savefolder
       Sets output directory for any fixed files.
       Default: <empty string>
    --success, --passed
       Logs successful validation checks.
       Default: false
    -v, --verbose
       Adds failed test information to text output.
       Default: false
    --version
       Displays veraPDF version information.
       Default: false

veraPDF is processing STDIN and is expecting an EOF marker.
If this isn't your intention you can terminate by typing an EOF equivalent:
 - Linux or Mac users should type CTRL-D
 - Windows users should type CTRL-Z
```

Comment: I am just coming back to this thread here (I asked the question some years ago) and find that https://github.com/veraPDF/veraPDF-library is still actively developed. Looks real good, from the surface of it. (I had never tried it though). Thanks for the effort!

Answer (score 9):

There is JHove. JHove is an open source tool for "validating" PDF/A compliance -- to a certain degree. Many libraries/institutions use it, so from this point of view it is a good answer to my question.

Recently, an article has been published about JHove in the context of modern document storage systems: http://www.pdfa.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/PDF_A_JHOVE_Friese_28112014_en1.pdf

To quote from it:

> JHOVE is an open source tool for identifying, characterizing and
>   validating common formats such as pdf, tiff, jpeg, aiff and wave. 
>   JHOVE includes validation modules for twelve different file formats,
>   including PDF.

and

> s many memory institutions primarily use the PDF format and the
>   quality of their files is not always enough of an argument for
>   converting them to
>   PDF/A, I believe that a standard PDF validator remains as necessary as
>   it always has been. In general, JHOVE will continue to be used,
>   despite its limitations, and decisions regarding the archivability of
>   a given file will be dependent on the results JHOVE gives.
>
> JHOVE can still be useful, provided users understand its error reports
>   and are aware of ways to resolve them. So far there is not a great
>   deal of documentation on this issue. Both nestor (AG Format
>   Recognition) and the Open Preservation Foundation aim to do their part
>   to improve this situation soon.

Here is a listing of JHove error message:
http://wiki.opf-labs.org/display/KB/JHOVE+Error+Messages

Comment: Someone should try and see how well iText-based validation goes: http://api.itextpdf.com/pdfa/

Comment: Note that the JHOVE PDF module is not actively supported and is now very out of date. I'd recommend veraPDF instead.

Answer (score 6):

## PDFBox

You might want to check out the (open source) Apache PDFBox library:

https://pdfbox.apache.org

This includes a PDF/A validator (PDF/A-1b only) which is pretty good. I would recommend to check out PDFBox 2.0.0 (which is currently a release candidate); you can find it here:

https://pdfbox.apache.org/download.cgi#20x

Then download the pre-built Preflight standalone binary (currently *preflight-app-2.0.0-RC1.jar*).

The following blog post summarises some work we did with Apache Preflight as part of a research project (it contains links to some further resources that you might find useful):

https://www.bitsgalore.org/2015/07/08/why-pdfa-validation-matters-part-2

## VeraPDF

On a side note, Bruno Lowagie mentioned a new EU-funded validator. This is now known as *VeraPDF*; they just (October 2015) published an early release that fully covers PDF/a1b (and partial support of PDF/A-1a, PDF/A-2 & PDF/A-3). More info here:

http://verapdf.org/2015/11/02/complete-pdfa-1b-coverage-now-available-in-0-6-release-of-verapdf/

This is still in its early stages, but they seem to be making quick progress, so definitely something to keep an eye on.