# FLOSS PDF reader conforming to ISO-32000-1

Tags: open-source, pdf, documentation-viewer, jpeg2000

What free software PDF readers claim they support ISO-32000-1?

How many *actually* support it, including e.g. JPEG 2000 compression? (Can someone link a test case?)

I'm interested mainly in answering the question for software listed in https://pdfreaders.org/, which I'm not sure were fully assessed for standard compliance.

Comment: Question split from http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/25405/floss-software-to-write-pdf-a-2-with-jpeg2000-compression/25489#comment35913_25489

Answer (score 2):

As for JPEG 2000 support, I tested a few viewers and these manage to open it: **Okular, Evince, XPDF** (`okular-14.12.3-1.fc21.x86_64`, `evince-3.14.2-4.fc21.x86_64`, `xpdf.x86_64 1:3.04-11.fc21`).

I failed with: `mupdf-1.5-5.fc21.x86_64` ([segmentation fault](http://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=696255)), `zathura-0.3.2-1.fc21.x86_64` and `qpdfview-0.4.13-1.fc21.x86_64`.

My [test case](http://bugs.ghostscript.com/attachment.cgi?id=11968&action=edit) was created with img2pdf from JPEG 2000 (JP2) images produced by ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 (+ JasPer 1.900.1-14ubuntu3.2) from 4-bit grayscale TIFFs about 30 MPx big.

Answer (score 1):

There is no PDF viewer which is fully, and completely compliant to every item in ISO-32000 (as far as I know).

The closest is Adobe Acrobat (Reader).

There is also no formal testing environment for ISO-32000 viewing compliance: We do not have any set of reference files which have to display properly, in order to conclusively make the tested PDF viewer "ISO-32000 compliant".