# Lossless combination of JPG/PNG images into a PDF file?

Tags: linux, pdf, images, pdf-generation

I'm looking for a utility the opposite of [`pdfimages`](https://www.xpdfreader.com/pdfimages-man.html): PDFs can hold within them images in various formats; `pdfimages` can list them and extract them (with or without conversion). What I want to do is take my images and put them in a PDF with **no conversion** (and thus no quality loss).

Required features:

- Runs on Linux
- Libre
- Open-source
- Supports at least JPG and PNG

Desired features:

- command-line
- GUI (separate or inherent)
- actively maintained
- small footprint
- native code (rather than Java etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### img2pdf

- Multi-platform
- Python-based
- command-line (binary name: `img2pdf`)
- Repository & website: [here](https://gitlab.mister-muffin.de/josch/img2pdf/blob/master/README.md).

A utility based on a Python library of the same name. To be honest, I just found it as an answer to [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/26084/software-to-quickly-join-many-jpg-images-into-one-pdf-without-recompressing) about Windows.

A typical command-line:

```
img2pdf foo.jpg bar.jpg -o combined.pdf
```

the images are wrapped in a PDF in sequence, losslessly and without recompression, as requested.

Installation is through the Python package management mechanism, [`pip`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pip_(package_manager)), i.e. you run:

```
pip install img2pdf
```

and it should just work. It will possibly pull some dependencies as well. Note, however, that this installation will be per-user, not system-wide.