# PDF testing software

Tags: pdf

I am looking for software to test PDF document content. Having responsibility for an infrastructure that generates invoices and documents, not having automated tests to ensure document content and structure, is a great pain.

So far I have come across 2 non-ideal products:

- http://pdfunit.com/ , commercial, Java and perl , single developer (not responded to email).
- https://sourceforge.net/projects/jpdfunit/ , open source, Java, unmaintained (last update 2013).

Another solution could be to leverage https://pdfbox.apache.org directly.

Are there other software alternatives for testing PDF content?

Comment: Similar question but specifically about PDF/A: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/18161/is-there-free-or-open-source-software-for-checking-pdf-a-compliance

Answer (score 1):

I have used [JHOVE](http://jhove.openpreservation.org/) to validate thousands of PDF files efficiently from a non-interactive program.

You can call it from command line:

```
jhove -m PDF myfile.pdf
```

JHOVE has a good documentation, please see the page about PDF:
http://jhove.openpreservation.org/modules/pdf/

Free, open source, large community.

Comment: Thanks. However, my objective goes beyond simply checking PDF/A compliance, e.g. 

* Does the company letter contain the correct signature of the new CEO?
* Does the company invoice contain the correct logo?

http://pdfunit.com/en/documentation/java/practice/ceo-signature.html
http://pdfunit.com/en/documentation/java/practice/new-logo.html

Jhove does not seem to have such capabilities?

Comment: Please list all of your requirements in details in your question, thank you!

Comment: Be sure to give examples of what must be tested.